# Is it possible to look 'behind' a mount point while still mounted?

Tags: filesystems, mount

I have two partitions, one mounted at / and one at /crypt. I'm using a `bind` mount to mount `/crypt/home` at `/home/` (and various others).

Problem is that I kinda need to look at the original `/home` dir now, but of course I just see the contents of `/crypt/home`.

I can't unmount this because to do so I have to be logged in, which means /home is in use...

Is there a way (perhaps another bind mount or something) that I can access the files under the original `/home` dir, without resorting to booting from a USB stick etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just login as root then you shouldn't have any problems with the `/home` mount. Still, if that is not possible, then you can simply `mount --bind / /elsewhere`. By default `--bind` type mounts are not recursive - and so the filesystems mounted to `/` will not follow it when it is `--bind` mounted somewhere else. You *can* recursively `--rbind` a mount elsewhere though.

For example:

```
findmnt /esp; findmnt /

TARGET SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/esp   /dev/sda1 vfat   rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

TARGET SOURCE                FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      /dev/sda2[/arch_root] btrfs  rw,relatime,compress-force=lzo,ssd,space_cache,autodefrag
```

As you can see, `/esp` is mounted on `/`.

```
mkdir /tmp/root
sudo mount --bind / /tmp/root
ls /esp /tmp/root/esp

/esp:
EFI/  shellia32.efi*  shellx64.efi*

/tmp/root/esp:
```

Now I'll get a file into `/tmp/root/esp`:

```
sudo touch /tmp/root/esp/blank_file
ls /esp /tmp/root/esp

/esp:
EFI/  shellia32.efi*  shellx64.efi*

/tmp/root/esp:
blank_file
```

So I've created a file in the directory where `/esp` is mounted. See?

```
sudo umount /boot /esp; ls /esp
blank_file

sudo mount -a; ls /esp
EFI/  shellia32.efi*  shellx64.efi*
```

I had to `umount /boot` *and* `/esp` because `/boot` is actually sourced from a bind mounted folder on `/esp`. Both of these are defined in `/etc/fstab` - which is why `mount -a` brought them back.

Comment: Thanks, `mount --bind / /elsewhere` did the trick `/elsewhere/home` was the 'original' version, as you pointed out. Many thanks for such a full explanation.